# Prices from database not working for smart paypal button

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway

I am currently creating the store for a website I am working for and I am attempting to use distinguishable prices forma a database for each product. I am using  a PayPal Smart button for this. Here is what I currently have.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'database');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "
    <script src='https://www.paypal.com/sdk...'></script>
    <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'blue',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',
            
        },
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '$row[paypal_price];'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>";
}
?>
```

My problem lies at the value, where the each product has a distinguishable value. When I try to make a payment however, the paypal page does not load. Am I doing something wrong? Have I misunderstood the use of the smart button?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you loading the PayPal SDK for every product? Seems unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the PayPal SDK for every product, only once per page -- echo it in its own `<script>` above the while statement or put it in the `<head>` of the page.

Your PHP string/variable syntax might be bad, try ending and concatenating:

```
value: " . $row[paypal_price] . "
```

Inspect or view source on the resulting page in the browser to verify that the result is what you expect.